# (...Array([random number]).keys().toString()) why the length and values of this expression always gives the same result?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, tostring, web-frontend

In Javascript, using spread operator we can iteration an Array.

`[...Array(5).keys()]` this gives a result ->

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

when I try to convert these number to a string

`[...Array(5).keys().toString()]` this gives a result ->

```
["[", "o", "b", "j", "e", "c", "t", " ", "A", "r", "r", "a", "y", " ", "I", "t", "e", "r", "a", "t", "o", "r", "]"]
```

`[...Array(10).keys().toString()]` this also gives a same result as above.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try using `console.log()` to see the values of each expression. For example, how does `console.log(Array(5).keys());` differ from `console.log(Array(5).keys().toString());`?

Comment: quick tip: use code fences to highlight the code instead of bolding it

Comment: because it simply returns "[Object] Array Iterator" string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array(5).keys()` is an Array Iterator. When you do

```
[...Array(5).keys().toString()]
```

you are not converting the keys to string, but you are trying to convert the iterator to String which gives you "[object Array Iterator]" as a character array.

You need to do:

```
[...Array(5).keys()].map(k => k.toString())
```

to convert all keys to String

Comment: Might be worth adding a reminder that `toString()` is method that basically every object has and its return value depends on which object it was called on.